# How do i calculate the probability of the relay in the circuits?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve my following probability question but I can't see how to make any progress. Any help will be highly appreciated

Question: The probability of the closing of the $i$-th relay in the circuits shown is given by $p_i$ for $i = 1,2,3,4,5$. If all relays function independently, what is the probability that a current flows between $A$ and $B$ for the respective circuits?

[image: Figures]

Comment: Have you tried systematically listing all the different combinations of closed switches for current to flow?

Comment: The way i tried is Let E1 be the event in which the current flows through (1,2,3) and E2  be the event in which the current flows through (4,5). So the current can flow through either E1 or E2. So P(E1 U E2) = P(E1)+ P(E2) - P(E1 n E2). But not sure if that is correct

Comment: But you have to allow for the possibility that, for example, in part a), current will flow if 4 and 5 are closed as well as any of the other switches being closed or open

Comment: I didn't thought about that. Thanks i will try

Answer (score 2):

Using $1-$ open, $1'-$closed:
$$a) \ \ P(1,2,3)+P(4,5)-P(1,2,3,4,5).\\
b) \ \ P(1,2,5)+P(3,4,5)-P(1,2,3,4,5).\\
c) \ \ P(1,4)-P(1,3,4,5)+P(2,5)-P(2,3,4,5)+P(1,3,5)-P(1,3,4,5)+\\
P(2,3,4)-P(2,3,4,5).$$

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but one way is simply to list the different combinations of gates which can be closed to allow current to flow. For example, for part b), we have

1. Three gates: 1,2,not3,not4,5; not1,not2,3,4,5
2. Four gates: 1,2,3,not4,5; 1,2,not3,4,5; 1,not2,3,4,5; not1,2,3,4,5
3. Five gates: 1,2,3,4,5

The other parts of the question can be done in the same way

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't seen the "bumped to homepage" before.

For case `a)` I'd suggest you look for the probability that no current flows. So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(I = 0)\ =\ &(1-p_1) \cdot (1-p_2) \cdot (1-p_3) + (1-p_4) \cdot (1-p_5)\\
&-\ (1-p_1) \cdot (1-p_2) \cdot (1-p_3)\cdot(1-p_4) \cdot (1-p_5)
\end{aligned}
$$

which follow from $\mathbb{P}(\{1,2,3\}\cup\{4,5\})=\mathbb{P}(\{1,2,3\})+\mathbb{P}(\{4,5\})-\mathbb{P}(\{1,2,3\}\cap\{4,5\})$.

At the end, calculate $\mathbb{P}(I = 0) =1-\mathbb{P}(I \neq 0)$.

Answer (score 0):

A general observation towards approaching this problem.

The layouts can be broken into parallel  circuits only one of which needs to be functional for current to flow. If the current through $i^{th}$ circuit is represented as $C_i$ and $E$ is the event that current flows, then one or more circuit needs to be complete for the current to flow. Thus,
$$
 P(E)= P \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} C_i \right)
$$

The individual cases can be solved through inclusion-exclusion principle.

For case (a), there are 2 possible circuits . $C_1 = \{1,2,3\}$,$C_2= \{4,5\}$. $P(C_1)= p_1p_2p_3$,$P(C_2)= p_4 p_5$

$$
\begin{align}
P(E)=P(C_1\cup C_2)  &= P(C_1)+ P(C_2)- P(C_1 \cap C_2)\\&
= p_1p_2p_3 + p_4 p_5 - p_1p_2p_3p_4 p_5
\end{align}
$$

For case(b), $C_1 = \{1,2,5\}$,$C_2= \{3,4,5\}$. $P(C_1)= p_1p_2p_5$, $P(C_2)= p_3 p_4 p_5$

$$
\begin{align}
P(E)=P(C_1\cup C_2)  &= P(C_1)+ P(C_2)- P(C_1 \cap C_2)\\&
= p_1p_2p_5 + p_3 p_4 p_5 - p_1p_2p_3p_4 p_5\\&
= p_5 (p_1p_2+ p_3 p_4 -p_1p_2p_3p_4)
\end{align}
$$

For case(c), $C_1 = \{1,4\}$,$C_2= \{1,3,5\}$,
$ C_3=\{2,3,4\}$ ,$C_4=\{2,5\}$. $P(C_1)= p_1p_4$,
$P(C_2)= p_1 p_3 p_5$,
$P(C_3)= p_2 p_3 p_4$ ,$P(C_4)= p_2 p_5$

$$
\begin{align}
P(E)=P(C_1\cup C_2\cup C_3\cup C_4)  &= P(C_1)+ P(C_2)+ P(C_3)+ P(C_4)
\\&- P(C_1 \cap C_2)- P(C_1 \cap C_3)
-P(C_1 \cap C_4)- P(C_2 \cap C_3)\\&
-P(C_2 \cap C_4) - P(C_3 \cap C_4)\\& 
+ P(C_1 \cap C_2 \cap C_3) + P(C_1 \cap C_2 \cap C_4)\\& +
P(C_2 \cap C_3 \cap C_4)+P(C_1 \cap C_3 \cap C_4)-
P(C_1 \cap C_2 \cap C_3 \cap C_4 )\\&
\end{align}
$$